# How to search Cloudinary by folder and transform?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm using the Node SDK to fetch all images from a specific folder in Cloudinary:

```js
const res = await cloudinary.v2.search.expression('folder:folder_name/subfolder_name')
  .max_results(12)
  .execute();
```

The images being returned are ~2-3 MB though, and so I'm needing to additionally transform them before sending them to my frontend. Is this possible with the Search API, or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

we would recommend using the Explicit call: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#explicit and make an eager transformation, this will allow you to be able fetch your images and transform them before sending them to your frontend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.